# User input not pushing in to vector correctly

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to allow the user to push an unlimited amount of integers in to a vector, however when i print the vector to the console, i receive `-1414812757-1414812757` rather than the numbers pushed in. This applies whether i enter multiple numbers `5 4 2` or just one number `5`.

What am i missing here? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> inputs;
    int userinp;

    std::cout << "Enter your numbers" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> userinp;
    inputs.push_back(userinp);

    std::cout << inputs[1] << inputs[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `inputs[0]` remember indexes in C and C++ start at 0!!!!!

Comment: You are only reading and pushing ***one*** number, which will be `inputs[0]`. Accessing the `[1]` and `[2]` elements (which don't exist) is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only input *one* number. There is no loop around:

```
std::cin >> userinp;
inputs.push_back(userinp);
```

That means that your access is out of bounds when you do this:

```
std::cout << inputs[1] << inputs[2];
```

You program therefore has [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and it could print just about anything - or make your computer explode (see [*nasal demons*](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

To read a number of numbers entered on a line, you could do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> inputs;
    std::cout << "Enter your numbers" << std::endl;
    
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);  // read a line
    std::istringstream is(line);   // put that line in an istringstream for extraction
    int userinp;
    while(is >> userinp) {         // extract numbers from the istringstream
        inputs.push_back(userinp);
    }

    // print all numbers in the vector
    for(int number : inputs) std::cout << number << '\n';

    if(inputs.size() >= 3) // check that the user actually entered at least 3 numbers
        std::cout << inputs[1] << inputs[2];
}
```

The loop `while(is >> userinp)` works like this:

- `is >> userinp` really makes a call to
  [`std::istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

  ```
  istream& operator>>( int& value );
  ```
- As you can see, `operator>>` returns an `istream` reference. It's a reference to the stream itself, which makes chained operations like `cin >> a >> b` possible.
- It also makes the `while` loop possible, because an `istream` has the member function [`operator bool() const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), so when an `istream` is used in boolean context, it will call that member function, which will return `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. When it fails extracting a number, the stream's [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) will be set and the while loop will end.

Comment: @CEPB The `operator []` [*performs no bounds checking*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) ... but the `.at()` function will throw an exception for out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake there. But how would i treat each number as an individual integer upon user input? E.G. if the user input `4 3 7 1` how could i push these as separate ints to the vector? I believe this was more what i was meaning to ask but that little index mistake got in the way of my question. Thanks

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thankyou very much this has been a huge learning experience for me, introducing me to sstream. My only remaining qualm is im struggling to get my head around the usage of the While loop. It makes sense to me that without it we will only get the first number of the string pushed in to the vector, but why does the while loop not end up continually pushing in the first number repeatedly? How does it know to move on to the next section of the string?

Comment: @Quack You're welcome. I added an explanation for the `while` loop.